# Is there any chance to exclude some columns and get the mean value of the rest seperately?

Tags: r

Needed an advice on how to exclude few columns in a data frame and calculate the mean value of the rest columns seperately. I could do it one by one but my wish is to know if I can do it by one code.

Age Height Weight    (excluding weight and getting the mean of age and height and print them seperately)

I'm expecting for a quicker and smarter solution.

Comment: Try `colMeans(df1[-3], na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.